# Linker errors with codelite, unittest++ and g++ on linux

Tags: c++, linker, g++, codelite, unittest++

I'm new to unit testing in c++, and writing c++ on Linux (Mint). I'm using CodeLite as my IDE. I have found several answers on stackoverflow about linker errors, but after hours of trying various solutions I have not succeeded in implementing a solution correctly.

I installed unittest++ through apt-get. The unittest++ header files were installed in /usr/include, so I added this to the Compiler linker options in Codelite (Right click project name->Settings, Compiler):
[Codelite screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zxZQZ.png)

I then have a very simple program, which consists entirely of one main.cpp file:

```
#include <unittest++/UnitTest++.h>
//See if unit tests are working
TEST(MyMath) {
    CHECK(false);
}

int main()
{
    UnitTest::RunAllTests();
    return 0;
}
```

Running the project at this point generates a stream of linker errors other users have experienced, for example:

main.cpp:4: undefined reference to `UnitTest::CurrentTest::Details()`

At this point, my understanding is that I now need to tell the g++ compiler about the object files and link them to the unittest++ files. And this is where I'm stuck. The only .o file I see is in *Debug/main.cpp.o* and running the command 
    g++ main.cpp -o main.cpp.o -Lunittest++
as well as variations with the I and o flags, but all of them return the same linker errors I get when I try to compile. I've also tried to copy every g++ line in the forums and only get various errors.

I've tried to find a solution in the g++ man pages, read about the flags I've been using and did not infer a solution. I then quickly got buried in quantity of pages in the man entry. The documentation for CodeLite and unittest++ seems woefully out of date, so I posted here on stackoverflow as a last resort.

I'm fairly certain I'm just making a rookie mistake. If someone has feedback, I'd be grateful.

Comment: If you want to build the object (.o) file and do *not* want to build the executable, you should add the `-c` flag : `g++ -c main.cpp -o main.cpp.o -Lunittest++` Maybe that's not the only problem though. I know the Boost Unit Test Framework better, so I can't tell without making additional research. I would suggest looking at examples of working test files with unittest++ if you still get errors.

Comment: By the way, don't look at the g++ manual unless you know what you're doing (I just looked, and I don't...). I just made a quick search on Google and found [this intro to g++](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~beechung/ref/gcc-intro.html). I only took a peek at it, but it looks like it has the basics of g++.

Comment: Thank you for your time and help. I was able to successfully create the object file using the `-c` flag. I read the intro to g++. Unfortunately, I'm still getting the _undefined reference_ errors. However, this helps me rule out other problems. I'll spend some time looking over possible causes and see if I can get useful information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your explanation, you try to link manually with `g++ -c main.cpp -o main.cpp.o -Lunittest++` , but the `-L` option gives the path to additional directories to search for libraries. You probably want `-lunittest++` to link with the unittest++ library. That library should provide the symbols you see in the "undefined reference" errors.

As a side note, "/usr/include" should be in the default search path and there's no need to add it explicitly.

Comment: You're right. The program now compiles beautifully. As a quick reference, what finally got it working was `g++ main.cpp -L/usr/include -lunittest++`

Comment: If it saves anybody else some time, these flags can be added in code lite by right clicking the project folder->Settings, select 'linker' in the side menu, and adding them to the 'Linker Options' field