# codelite unittest++/UnitTest++.h: no such file or directory

Tags: c++, unit-testing, codelite, unittest++

I am trying to do unit testing with C++/Codelite. I have UnitTest++ plugin installed from codelite-plugins package (Ubuntu 18.04). I can also see this:

```
$ ls -la /usr/include | grep Unit
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root   4096 Mar  2 11:47 UnitTest++

$ sudo dpkg -l | grep unittest++
ii  libunittest++-dev         2.0.0-2      amd64        unit testing framework for c++, static library and headers
ii  libunittest++2:amd64      2.0.0-2      amd64        unit testing framework for c++, runtime library
```

So I create a test project in Codelite and I add this:

```
#include <unittest++/UnitTest++.h> // This line and main are auto-created

TEST(SanityTest) 
{
    CHECK_EQUAL(1, 1);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    return UnitTest::RunAllTests();
}
```

Now I would expect test results after I press CTRL+F5. But when I do, I only get a popup window saying there are no tests:

[image]

I also noticed that when I go to **Build > Build Project** I get an error message:

> fatal error: unittest++/UnitTest++.h: No such file or directory

I also found [THIS ANSWER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42657198/linker-errors-with-codelite-unittest-and-g-on-linux) and tried different variation of console commands as per answer/comments there, but I always get the same no such file or directory error.

Any idea what I am missing?

**EDIT:**

Build log as per Stephen's Newell request:

```
/bin/sh -c '/usr/bin/make -j8 -e -f  Makefile'
----------Building project:[ Test - Debug ]----------
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/callmebob/Documents/workspace-codelite/cpp/Test'
/usr/bin/g++  -c  "/home/callmebob/Documents/workspace-codelite/cpp/Test/main.cpp" -g  -o Debug/main.cpp.o -I. -I/usr/include/unittest++
/home/callmebob/Documents/workspace-codelite/cpp/Test/main.cpp:1:10: fatal error: unittest++/UnitTest++.h: No such file or directory
 #include "unittest++/UnitTest++.h"
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
Test.mk:95: recipe for target 'Debug/main.cpp.o' failed
make[1]: *** [Debug/main.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/callmebob/Documents/workspace-codelite/cpp/Test'
Makefile:4: recipe for target 'All' failed
make: *** [All] Error 2
====2 errors, 0 warnings====
```

Also if I right-click the project, go to **Settings > Compiler**, I can see:

> Included Paths = /usr/include/unittest++

Comment: Have you verified the files actually exist?  I don't use ubuntu (or any apt-based distro), but they're probably under `/usr/include`.  Also, please include the full compilation line (it's probably above the error you already provided).

Comment: Build log added. Also on top of my post there is output "ls -la /usr/include" where you can see UnitTest++. It's with capitals and doesn't have .h at the end. I tired including with no .h with the same results though.

Comment: Based on your `ls` output, my hunch is that the directory name in your code is incorrect.  Try changing the first line to `#include <UnitTest++/UnitTest.h>` (you may want to verify the contents of `/usr/include/UnitTest++` first).

Comment: @StephenNewell: you were correct. I had to change it to <UnitTest++/UnitTest++.h> at the end. From here, I was able to build, but now on CTRL+F5 I was getting nothing at all. Seems like I have to do CTRL+F9 (Build and run) to get results - not sure why, but it works. If you want add an answer and I will accept it as you pointed me to the correct direction.

Comment: Glad it worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your `ls` output, it looks like you should change your first line to this:

```
#include <UnitTest++/UnitTest++.h>
```

I'm not sure why the answer you linked to worked with a lowercase directory name; the examples in the project documentation all use the mixed-case directory name.

Comment: Yes, that's a bit weird with the lowercase. My initial code was also auto-generated with lowercase, like in my example. Probably best if I report a bug.